# Why is Guzzle POST showing this foreach error?

Tags: php, json, guzzle

I am using

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
```

and I am running

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'base_uri' => 'http://myapp.loc',
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ]
        ]);
```

Then

```
$response = $client->post('/api/books',  [
                'json' => [
                    'bookId'    => '123',
                    'title'     => 'My Random Test Book',
                    'author'    => 'Test Author'
                ]
        ]);
```

But I get

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException : Client error: `POST http://myapp.loc/api/books` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
>   Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

If I use the same route and data in Postman everything works, so the route and method is ok.

I have tried also

```
 $response = $client->post('/api/books', [
        'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ],
        'body' => json_encode([
            'bookId'    => '123',
            'title'     => 'My Random Test Book',
            'author'    => 'Test Author'
        ])
    ]);
```

but it returns the same foreach error.

Any ideas on why Guzzle is showing this foreach error?

Digging a bit into this with Xdebug, the error arises from `\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Stream` at the `fread` point

```
public function read($length)
{
   ...

    $string = fread($this->stream, $length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to form the request like:

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'http://myapp.loc/api/books', [
            'form_params' => [
               'parameters' => json_encode([[
                    'bookId'    => '123',
                    'title'     => 'My Random Test Book',
                    'author'    => 'Test Author'
                ]])
            ]
        ]);
```